# Latest function callback is not caught in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the example bellow, Child component calls onFinish callback 5 seconds after clicking on button. The problem is that onFinish callback can change in those 5 seconds, but the it will call the last caught one.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Child = ({ onFinish }) => {
  const [finished, setFinished] = useState(false);

  const finish = async () => {
    setFinished(true);
    setTimeout(() => onFinish(), 5000);
  };

  return finished ? (
    <p>Wait 5 seconds and increment while waiting.</p>
  ) : (
    <button onClick={finish}>Click here to finish</button>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((c) => c + 1)}>Increment</button>
      <Child onFinish={() => alert(`Finished on count: ${count}`)} />
    </>
  );
}
```

The workaroud for this one is to replace finish with the following:

```
  const cb = useRef();
  cb.current = onFinish;
  const finish = async () => {
    setFinished(true);
    setTimeout(() => cb.current(), 5000);
  };
```

Is there a better approach to update the callback to the latest one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can check the current state and compare it with prev state like

```
setFinished((prevState) => newState)
```

Comment: It's not about `setFinished`, it's about `setTimeout` which has captured some previous onFinish callback.